# Xamarin ListView display objects of different types

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have objects of 3 different types:

```
public class WordPressPost
Tweetinvi.Models.ITweet
Ical.Net.CalendarComponents.CalendarEvent
```

They all have certain attributes in common such as a title, content, date of publishing, and optionally an image url.

How can I display these 4 types of objects in the same ListView using DataBinding in XAML?

The attributes all have different names within the different classes, meaning I couldn't just use something like `{Binding Title}`. Additionally, I have so far only thought of using an `ObservableCollection<object>` or converting the all of the objects to a new uniform class which houses the aforementioned attributes:

```
public class CardItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }  
}
```

Edit:
Jason's recommendation to convert all the objects to the class above was successful.

Comment: I'd suggest using a common Interface or base class, but if the property name are not consistent between the classes then that will not work.  Your best bet is to convert them to a common class to use for display

Comment: Based on my research, `ObservableCollection<object>` is better choice, you could define a object to include these attributes